# Is there a closed form to this quadratic program?

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization, duality-theorems, quadratic-programming, karush-kuhn-tucker

### Problem :

I am currently trying to solve some optimization problem to get some information about a matrix. In the following, when we have a matrix $A\in\mathbb R^{m\times n}$, $0\leq A$ means that $0\leq A_{ij}$ for all $i$ and $j$. The objective is quadratic and its dual is
\begin{align*}
\min_{\substack{U\in\mathbb R^{m\times m}:\\0\leq U}} \operatorname{Tr}[(I+U) M (I+U^T)]
\end{align*}
with $M$ a PSD and symmetric matrix in $\mathbb R^{m\times m}$.

After some simplifications, the KKT conditions are equivalent to (the Lagrange multipliers are $M(I+U^T)$)
\begin{align*}
\begin{cases}
0\leq U\\
0\leq M (I+U^T)\\
\operatorname{Tr}[U M (I+U^T)]=0
\end{cases}
\end{align*}

Since we are minimizing a convex function under convex domain, the KKT are sufficient, therefore any $U$ satisfying those is optimal for the dual problem.

Note that If we know the indices $\mathcal I=\{ (i,j) : U_{ij}>0 \}$, then from the three KKT conditions, we get that $[M(I+U^T)]_{ji}=0$ for all $(i,j)\in\mathcal I$, this gives a system of $|\mathcal I|$ linear equations in $|\mathcal I|$ unknown and can therefore be solved efficiently.

I implemented this using a quadratic programing solver and after some inspection, it feels like the following is true :

> For any $i$, $j$, if we have $M_{ij} > 0$ then we have $U_{ij} = 0$.

I cannot prove or disprove it, any help would be appreciated.

---

### Discussions :

This problem can be reduced to a much simpler one with vectors. Let $u_i$ be the $i$'th line vector in $U$, then
\begin{align*}
\operatorname{Tr}[(I+U)M(I+U^T)] &= \sum_i (u_i+e_i^T) M (u_i^T + e_i)
\end{align*}
Therefore we can find $U$ by solving $m$ problems of the form
\begin{align*}
u_i^T \in \operatorname{argmin}_{0\leq u} (u+e_i)^T M (u+e_i) 
\end{align*}
for each $i$.

The KKT conditions of such problem are given by splitting the KKT above similarly
\begin{align*}
\begin{cases}
0\leq u\\
0\leq M (u+e_i)\\
u^T M (u+e_i)=0
\end{cases}
\end{align*}

It is not to hard to prove that for the $i$'th problem, the solution $u_i$ has $0$ entry at index $i$. Indeed the unconstrained optimum is $-e_i$ and if we have a candidate $u$ with $u_i >0$, then $\frac{1}{1+u_i} u + \frac{u_i}{1+u_i} (-e_i)$ is a convex combination of our candidate with the unconstrained optimum that has all positive components. This means that $u_i=0$.

Note that in case we know what indices of $u$ are zero, then we can obtain the value of the rest by solving a simple linear system. Indeed if $\mathcal I=\{ j : u_j>0 \}=\{ j_1, j_2,\dots, j_k \}$, let
\begin{align*}
u_{\mathcal I} &= \begin{bmatrix}
u_{j_1}\\
u_{j_2}\\
\vdots\\
u_{j_k}
\end{bmatrix}\\
M_{\mathcal I\mathcal I} &= \begin{bmatrix}
M_{j_1j_1} & M_{j_1j_2}&\dots&M_{j_1j_k}\\
M_{j_2j_1} & M_{j_2j_2}&\dots&M_{j_2j_k}\\
\vdots&\vdots&\ddots&\vdots\\
M_{j_kj_1} & M_{j_kj_2}&\dots&M_{j_kj_k}\\
\end{bmatrix}\\
m_{i\mathcal I} &= \begin{bmatrix}
M_{ij_1}\\
M_{ij_2}\\
\vdots\\
M_{ij_k}
\end{bmatrix}
\end{align*}
Then from the KKT conditions, $u_{\mathcal I}$ satisfies $M_{\mathcal I\mathcal I} u_{\mathcal I}=-m_{i\mathcal I}$. This means that in order to solve the original problem, we could search what are the indices that are zero.

From this, I think we can rephrase the above problem as follow :

> Suppose we have
> \begin{align*}
> M=\begin{bmatrix}
> m_{11}&m_1^T\\
> m_1&M_{11}
> \end{bmatrix}
> \end{align*}
> a positive definite matrix of dimension $m\times m$, and a vector $0<u\in\mathbb R^{m-1}$ such that
> \begin{align*}
> M_{11} u = -m_1
> \end{align*}
> Then $m_1<0$.

Comment: Is $I$ the identity matrix? It is being summed with the nonsquare matrix $U$.

Comment: @Blake yes $I$ is the identity and $U$ is squared of dimension $m\times m$.

Comment: Oh I see, I misread the dimensions

Comment: Am I missing something, or you haven't included the KKT multipliers and complementary slackness condition?

Comment: @V.S.e.H. Maybe this isn't very clear in the way I formulated it, but if the multipliers are given by $V$, then you need $V=M(I+U^T)$ as well as $\operatorname{Tr}(UV)=0$, I therefore simplified those and wrote "After some simplification" which is not optimal. Do you think I should reformulate ?

Comment: No, this is good, just was a bit confused with the extent of your simplification.

Comment: Just checked the gradient calculation again, and isn't $V = (I+U)M$? Also, we have $\operatorname{Tr}(V^TU) = 0$. This only changes your 2nd condition. I like your reduction to vector optimization.

Comment: @V.S.e.H. Yeah I think I used $\operatorname{Tr}[VU]=0$ as which essentially transposed $V$, but of course if you plug your $V$ in $\operatorname{Tr}(V^T U)$ you get $\operatorname{Tr}(M (I+U)^T U)=\operatorname{Tr}(U M (I+U)^T)$ which is the same.